# Bitmap Data .draw() with transform matrix

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, matrix, bitmapdata

I'm working on a project wherein a user can take a snapshot of themselves using their webcam and then edit this image by transforming scale and rotation and save the result.

I've got most of it working, the user can take a snapshot of themselves, transform the object using Senocular's Transform Tool and i'm using .draw() to then save this transformed object. The problem is .draw() is only grabbing data from the top left corner of the stage. It is drawing the transformed object but only from the top left corner.

Why does it only draw from the top left corner and how can i get set the coordinates to only draw from the area where the captured image is set?

Thanks.

You can view the file as is at: http://s46264.gridserver.com/dev/dave/pb-photo/index.html

And i've zipped the FLA and relevant classes at http://s46264.gridserver.com/dev/dave/pb-photo/pb-photo.zip

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import com.senocular.display.transform.*;

// create container for captured image to apply Transform Tool to
var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(box);
box.graphics.beginFill(0xAACCDD);
box.graphics.drawRect(-160, -120, 320, 240); // xreg, yreg, width, height (x-y = width-height / 2 to set centered registration point)
box.x = 520;
box.y = 140;

// create the Transform Tool
var tool:TransformTool = new TransformTool(new ControlSetStandard());
addChild(tool);

// select the box with the transform tool when clicked. 
// deselect when clicking on the stage
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tool.select);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tool.deselect);

var snd:Sound = new camerasound(); //new sound instance for the "capture" button click

var bandwidth:int = 0; // Maximum amount of bandwidth that the current outgoing video feed can use, in bytes per second.
var quality:int = 100; // This value is 0-100 with 1 being the lowest quality. 

var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setQuality(bandwidth, quality);
cam.setMode(320,240,30,false); // setMode(videoWidth, videoHeight, video fps, favor area)
var video:Video = new Video();
video.attachCamera(cam);
video.x = 20;
video.y = 20;
addChild(video);

// create bitmap to hold initial capture and addChild to transform box
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width,video.height);

var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
bitmap.x = -160;
bitmap.y = -120;
box.addChild(bitmap);

capture_mc.buttonMode = true;
capture_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,captureImage);

function captureImage(e:MouseEvent):void {
    snd.play();
    bitmapData.draw(video);
    save_mc.buttonMode = true;
    save_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSaveJPG);
    save_mc.alpha = 1;
}

save_mc.alpha = .5;

// save transformed bmp to new object and addChild to holder_mc
function onSaveJPG(e:Event):void{

    var m:Matrix = box.transform.matrix;
    trace(m);

    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(320, 240, true, 0xCCCCCCCC);
    bmp.draw(box, m);

    var newbmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
    holder_mc.addChild(newbmp);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw the entire stage and then select pixels you want using copyPixels(). Method is shown below :)

```
private function drawImage():void
{
    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight)
    bmp.draw(stage);

    var _newBmp:BitmapData = new bitmapData(WidthOfTheImage, HeightOfTheImage, TransParancy, FillColor);
    _newBmp.copyPixels(bmp, new Rectangle(XofTheImage, YOftheImage, WidthOfTheImage, HeightOfTheImage), new point());
}
```

_newBmp is the bitmapdata you want :)

Answer (score 5):

Funnily enough I'm working on something very similar at the moment.  You can draw a certain area of your target by passing x and y offsets into draw as part of a matrix:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(target.width,target.height,true,0);
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,-target.x,-target.y);
bmd.draw(this,mat);
```

Note in particualr that the x and y passed into the matrix are set negative.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the bounds of the clip will give you the exact area you want to copy.

```
var bounds:Rectangle = mc.getBounds(mc);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(int(bounds.width + 0.5), int(bounds.height + 0.5), true, 0);
bitmapData.draw(mc, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y));
```